# CouchDB cross domain access from web?

Tags: couchdb, cross-domain

Currently, web application need to offer some kind of cross-domain HTTP header to access data on other domain: http://openfontlibrary.org/wiki/Web_Font_linking_and_Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

Is there any way to configure CouchDB to support unlimited cross-domain access? I'm using the db in-house purpose only.

Answer (score 3):

There is a JIRA ticket about [CouchDB cross-origin resource sharing](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-431).

Recently, I submitted a patch enabling CORS. I expect a modified version of the patch will be included in CouchDB 1.2.0, the next stable release.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're on the right track. CouchDB supports master-master replication that is very easy to configure. So you could put your fonts into Couch and have other font users replicate your fonts onto their own Couch servers. This would let them access your fonts as often as they want without having to head over to your server each time they want to pull a font (their CouchDB would copy all the fonts once and then the clients would pull from that Couch node instead of yours).

The added benefit of Couch is that if a user on another Couch node adds a font, the master-master system will replicate it to your node so you can see it locally. This is a pretty handy feature that many folks fail to recognize about Couch.

See more here: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/replication.html